# Extract data from data.frame based on coordinates in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, rows

So here is what my problem is. I have a really big `data.frame` woth two columns, first one represents x coordinates (rows) and another one y coordinates (columns), for example:

```
x y

1 1

2 3

3 1

4 2

3 4
```

In another frame I have some data (numbers actually):

```
a b c d

8 7 8 1

1 2 3 4

5 4 7 8

7 8 9 7

1 5 2 3
```

I would like to add a third column in first `data.frame` with data from second `data.frame` based on coordinates from first `data.frame`. So the result should look like this:

```
x y z

1 1 8

2 3 3

3 1 5

4 2 8

3 4 8
```

Since my `data.frames` are really big the for loops are too slow. I think there is a way to do this with apply loop family, but I can't find how. Thanks in advance (and sorry for ugly message layout, this is my first post here and I don't know how to produce this nice layout with code and proper `data.frames` like in another questions).

Comment: Did you look into [merging data frames](http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html)? If coordinates appear in both, no need for looping.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple indexing question. No need in external packages or `*apply` loops, just do

```
df1$z <- df2[as.matrix(df1)]
df1
#   x y z
# 1 1 1 8
# 2 2 3 3
# 3 3 1 5
# 4 4 2 8
# 5 3 4 8
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the most simple and fastest solution

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution: (`df1` and `df2` are coordinates and numbers as data frames):

```
 df1$z <- mapply(function(x,y) df2[x,y], df1$x, df1$y )
```

It works if the last `y` in the first data frame is corrected from `5` to `4`. 
I guess it was a typo since you don't have 5 columns in the second data drame.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this.

First, use [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) for fast merging; then convert your data frames (I'll call them `dt1` with coordinates and `vals` with values) to `data.table`s.

```
dt1<-data.table(dt)
vals<-data.table(vals)
```

Second, put `vals` into a new `data.table` with coordinates:

```
vals_dt<-data.table(x=rep(1:dim(vals)[1],dim(vals)[2]),
                    y=rep(1:dim(vals)[2],each=dim(vals)[1]),
                    z=matrix(vals,ncol=1)[,1],key=c("x","y"))
```

Now merge:

```
setkey(dt1,x,y)[vals_dt,z:=z]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `data.table` package and update `df1` *by reference*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, z := df2[cbind(x, y)]][]
#    x y z
# 1: 1 1 8
# 2: 2 3 3
# 3: 3 1 5
# 4: 4 2 8
# 5: 3 4 8
```